# Tinny sound on Lenovo U510

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I want to ask, how can I tweak my sounds from speakers. It now sounds so tinny, like the sound comes from a tin can. In Windows, I don't have any problems with it, but in Ubuntu it sounds just awful.

In search of a solution, I spent approximately six hours. I tried to reinstall the alsa drivers, tweak settings in alsamixer and I also try to restart pulseaudio. Nothing worked for me.

The off sound can be heard when someone in the track (sound) speaks a bit louder. When someone speaks normal, it's little bit better, and when I lower the volume it sounds even less tinny, but it can still be heard.

Do you have any tips?

I'm having this issue on a Lenovo Ideapad U510 with Intel Core i3. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

and information from alsa-info.sh is located here: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=907d60a47fd8c280bc33db9997d83a196dca96eb

Comment: "tinny"? you mean "low" as "inaudible"?

Comment: No, it's like the sound goes from tincan. There is no bass sound. I don't know, how to explain it better.

Answer (score -2):

you can try with alsamixer with the terminal. You can change the type for channel and have the level sound for the speaker changed.

Comment: can you please provide details on how to do this?

Comment: This might help for volume, but "tinny-ness"?

Comment: I have this pb with a previous version. And I know to change alsamixer default 2 chan in 6 chan (for me) resolve (for me again) my pb. May be it was luck. But the other solution is to see the "pilot" or oss (but not very fun for multi flux). I have the same audio chipset but I don't have this pb with this version of Ubuntu.